# DateTime format returns string

Tags: php, datetime

I am using `DateTime` to change about the formats of my $date string

```
$date = (new DateTime($date))->format('D, M d, Y');
```

However, calling `gettype(Sdate)` afterwards gives the returned value as a string. The [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) says it should

> Return(s) a new DateTime instance or FALSE on failure.

I am getting the instance, but is the intended behaviour to have the returned format in a string? Is using `strtotime` afterwards always a must despite using the DateTime function or am I doing somthing completely wrong?

Comment: No, the manual says that the [format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method returns a string.... `public string DateTime::format ( string $format )`

Comment: But why would you consider using `strtotime` at all when you're using DateTime objects.... that's like taking the engine out of your Ferrari and replacing it with a lawn-mower engine

Comment: If you want to actually create a DateTime instance, then use `$dateObject = new DateTime($date);` and you can do what you want with the `$dateObject` after that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at the documentation page of the [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method, which indeed accepts a string specifying a certain format and returns a DateTime object.

[`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) on the other hand accepts a format string and returns the date as an string.

I believe this is what you actually want:

```
$myDate = '2014-12-07 10:00:00';
$dateTime = new DateTime($myDate);
```

`format()` would allow you to recover the same string from the DateTime instance:

```
$originalDate = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```